# Angular create my own attributes for a button element (not with ngClass or class)

Tags: angular, angular12

I am using Angular 12 and I've created a button component which will contain a button element.
I also know how to pass data using @Input, Output etc ... button what I need to do is to have something like Material UI for Angular does:

If I have this:

```
<button></button>
```

How can I wire the color class without using ngClass or Class but like this:

```
<button color="myclass"></button> ?
```

Comment: You can use the angular directive [link](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to create a custom button element which accepts a string denoting a color as an input property or want to create a custom attribute directive that colors your button element based on a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an attribute directive for the button element, that internally does take input and applies it on the button.

[attribute-directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

They have almost given the same example of what you need. : [example](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#setting-the-value-with-user-input)